# How do I disable an iOS app that my customers already have on their phones?

Tags: ios, native, disable

My company has an iOS app that we removed from the App Store several years ago when we transitioned to a PWA.

We have many existing customers who try and use the app to access our program. The app still functions at a certain level but often fails as a result of many developments that have occurred since the app was removed.

I would like it if the app were just to be diabled when the customer opens it. Ideally, with a message that says "this app is no longer supported. Please visit our website and download our PWA"

Any way to do this without updating the current app?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: To add to @Paulw11, maybe you could submit an update to the app, maybe even targeting the iOS version that broke things? On launch you could pop up something. (Apple may not approve of this, but it may be worth a try.)